# sightly ( ACS - Commons) generic list

Tags: aem, sightly

I am new to AEM. 
I have used ACS commons generic list for populating the drop down values. I have added the titles for french and english under localisation part of generic list for each item.consider my js(js based approach in sightly) would return itemList (for ex: var itemList = list.getItems();).
         how can I get the locale based title available in generic list(for ex, how can i get the french title which i have included under localisation part), in place of ${list.title} mentioned in the below HTML code:

```
     <select data-sly-use.frm="sample_form.js"   data-sly-list.list="${frm}">
                            <option value="${list.value}">${list.title}
```

OR what is the other possibility to get the locale based title available in generic list with the help of sightly.

Could anyone help me on this. Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: how are you populating this list in your backend logic? Is is authorable or some other mechanism is there?

Comment: sample_form.js (I am getting the ACS-commons generic list here)

"use strict";
use(function () {
     var resolver = sling.getRequest().getResource().getResourceResolver();
 var pageManager = resolver.adaptTo(Packages.com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageManager);
 var listPage = pageManager.getPage("/etc/acs-commons/lists/sampleoption");
 var list = listPage.adaptTo(Packages.com.adobe.acs.commons.genericlists.GenericList);
     var sampList= list.getItems();

return sampList;
 });
 How can I get the French title (which I have given under the localisation part available in the Commons Generic list items)

Answer (score 0):

Using JS API you can create custom Arrays that then can be used by the data-sly-list in order to traverse through all the information. I have done this successfully and I like the flexibility and separation of responsibilities.